# How to fix OTS parsing error when importing fonts

Tags: angular

I am importing a font and using it in a css file in an angular app

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'tes';
  src: url('../kfonts/tes.eot?#iefixn1z373') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../kfonts/tes.woff?n1z373') format('woff'), url('../kfonts/tes.ttf?n1z373') format('truetype'), url('../kfonts/tes.svg?n1z373#lg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

If I run the angular server within webstorm, all works fine and fonts show up correctly.  If I build the app using package.json and run it in nginx,  fonts don't show up,  Chrome gives the  following error:

Failed to decode downloaded font: https://localhost/tes.0392227eb4b4510402ab.woff?n1z373

OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 1008813135

Failed to decode downloaded font: https://localhost/tes.269f233c78c029ba7cce.ttf?n1z373

OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 1008813135

Comment: The magic number `1008813135` is `0x3c21444f` in hex, which again is `<!DO` in ASCII. So you are passing html data starting with `<!DOCTYPE` instead of font data to the font parser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the fonts are in `src/assets/kfonts`, for example. And that relative path to `index.html` relates to the location of fonts in `url` - most likely this is a path issue, that you can't reach for assets you want.

And then access them

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'tes';
  src: url('./assets/kfonts/tes.eot?#iefixn1z373') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('./assets/kfonts/tes.woff?n1z373') format('woff'), 
  url('./assets/kfonts/tes.ttf?n1z373') format('truetype'), 
  url('./assets/kfonts/tes.svg?n1z373#lg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I have asset in angular.json as "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/kfonts"
            ],   and the path is correct because the same code works fine inside webstorm.  I see icons fine. Fonts look good

Comment: Did you try to replace your `..` from path to `url('./kfonts/tes.woff?n1z373') format('woff')`? My suspicion is that webpack serves html.index differently when you build with `package.json` and it can't reach the assets.

Comment: just tried replacing .. with .   but i get error Can't resolve './kfonts/tes.woff..''

Comment: Seems like webpack is able to reach the asset fine but it changes something in the font and then Chrome can not decode it.  Same code works fine from within Webstorm CLI server

Comment: The files could be corrupt as well, try downloading/converting again. But also strat debugging and adding fonts one by one to see which ones fail?